# Referencing an array to a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to refer a pointer to an array by another pointer.

Example:

```
void exp()
{
    double var[2];
    exp1(&var[0]);
    printf("\n varvalue is %lf\n",var[0]);
}

void exp1(double *var)
{
    //updating the value
    *var[0]=4.0;
    exp2(&var[0]);
}

void exp2(double *var)
{
    *var[0]=7.0;
}
```

This should update the value as `7.0`(the last update).I am getting an array like *invalid argument type of unary(*)* . How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `*` operator from `*var[0]`.  In function `exp1`, it should be

```
var[0] = 4.0;
```

In function `exp2`, it should be

```
var[0] = 7.0;
```

Or you can remove `[0]`. `*var` is equivalent to `var[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

In `exp1` and `exp2` the variable `var` is a pointer. So using normal array subscript is the same as dereferencing the variable. You try to dereference the variables *twice*.

A good thing to know is that `*var` is the same as `var[0]`. Or to be more precise `*(var + x)` is the same as `var[x]`. (And as a curiosity, due to the commutative nature of addition, `*(var + x)` is the same as `*(x + var)` which leads to `var[x]` be the same as `x[var]`.)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra `*` in `*var[0]`.

`var[0]` is the same as `*(var + 0)`, or `*var`, which is already what you need to assign.